# Matching dict keys with user input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a python pizza app (yes I know there is a ton of them) but, I am coming across a scenario that I need help understanding.

```
price = 0

toppings = {
    'mushrooms': .5,
    'onions': .5,
    'pepperoni': 1,
    'extra-cheese':1
}

pizzaSize = {
    'small': 8,
    'medium': 10,
    'large': 12,
    'x-large': 14
}


order1 = input("Welcome to the pizza store what size pizza can we get for you (small, medium, large, or x-large): " )

print(order1)

if order1 == pizzaSize.keys():
    print(order1)
```

I understand that this code will not work when it comes to the `if order1` part. However, I am interested in understanding how I could take the input and match it with a key of the dict `pizzaSize`.

Here is why I want to do that. I want to take user input and check and see if it is contained inside the `pizzaSize` dict.

If the string is contained there, I want to add the value of that key that matched to the `price` variable set at the top. Thank you all!

Comment: `pizzaSize.get(order1, None)` should do it for you.

Comment: @DaveIdito None is already the default value ;)

Comment: @azro thanks. I don't know why and when the extra argument of `None` for `get` became almost a muscle memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need may use an `.get()` to get the corresponding value from the dict, if it doesn't exist you'll a `None`

```
order1 = input("Welcome to the pizza store what size pizza can we get for you (small, medium, large, or x-large): " )

size_price = pizzaSize.get(order1)
if size_price is not None:
    price += size_price
else:
    print(f"Sorry the size '{order1}' doesn't exist")
    exit(1)
```

Comment: File "pizzaAppv2.py", line 21, in <module>
    sizePrice = pizzaSize.get(pizzaSize)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

that is the error you get if you do it like you said

Comment: @aroe there was a mistake, look again the new code

Comment: That's a good point but I don't think it matters. Either way it's just adding the new price to the price var. However it is erroring now see above ^.

Comment: fixed, I passed it the new var of order1 and it output the correct price.

Comment: Very sorry @azro for not accepting your answer! Just did it now and it was very useful thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it multiple ways:

1. Use if `order1 in pizzaSize`, if it is true, add the price
2. Use `.get()` to see if the size is present in the dictionary and react accordingly.
3. Use `pizzaSize[order1]` and catch the exception if the key is not present in dict.